# I am trying to write an add function that add an integer to each element in the list

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, addition

It can be done by using for loop, but i want to do it by writing an add function.

```py
a =[1,2,3,4]
for i in a: 
    print(i+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're after creating a new list, you can use the `map` function and convert it into a list, but this is equivalent to writing a `for` loop:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = list(map(lambda x: x + 1, a))
```

If you want to create an `add` method for this, you can define it this way:

```py
def add(l):
    return list(map(lambda x: x + 1, l))

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = add(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting the logic inside the function and then call it for getting the value:

```py
def add_one(array):
    for i in range(0, len(array)): 
       array[i] += 1
    return array

array = [1,2,3,4]

result = add_one(array)

print(result)
```